# Rails form mysteriously errors. Rollback every time even though params are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

I've got a user signup form with standard stuff. It was working fine, but now it's totally broken, and the error messages are completely unhelpful. I hopped into this existing app several weeks ago. And even if I checkout a commit from before I put ANY code into this project, the form still doesn't work. By 'not work', I mean it throws errors as if the forms are completely blank ('Please enter an e-mail', 'Please enter a password'), when they most certainly were not blank. Here's the relevant code...

**MODEL:**

```
include FormsHelper
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :time_zone, :state,
                  :birthday, :oauth_id, :oauth_provider_display_name,
                  :admin, :vagrant, :favorite_shoe, :race_manager, :auto_submission,
                  :country
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save

      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else

      Rails.logger.info(resource.errors.inspect)
      flash.now[:error] = I18n.t('activerecord.template.body')
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

**VIEW**

```
<%= f.input :email, :required => true,
                    :autofocus => true,
                    :input_html => { :autocomplete => 'off' },
                    :as => 'email' %>
<% if resource.oauth_id.present? %>
  <%#
    Check if we're coming here from an OAuth-typ registration. The value here doesn't really matter
    because it'l be auto-generated again on create. This is just for form validation purposes.
  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :password %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :password_confirmation,
                     :value => f.object.password %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.input :password,
              :required => true,
              :hint => controller.controller_name == 'account' ? "Leave blank if you don't want to update your password." : nil,
              :input_html => { :value => f.object.password, :autocomplete => 'off' } %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
              :label => "Confirm password",
              :required => true,
              :input_html => { :value => f.object.password_confirmation, :autocomplete => 'off' } %>
<% end %>
<%= f.input :first_name, :required => true %>
<%= f.input :last_name, :required => true %>
```

**Here's the Log output**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-31 16:20:43 -0800
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IR6YzpsgwrfLwP0snZ7l1c6RTjhtv/tOtDtHp/I1Agc=", "user"=>{"oauth_id"=>"", "oauth_provider_display_name"=>"", "email"=>"blakester99999@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"Hey", "last_name"=>"There", "country"=>"United States", "state"=>"CA", "gender"=>"m", "birthday(2i)"=>"1", "birthday(3i)"=>"1", "birthday(1i)"=>"2003", "time_zone"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "favorite_shoe"=>"Asics"}, "commit"=>"Complete Registration"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffdaf5babd0 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: false, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, gender: nil, state: nil, birthday: nil, time_zone: nil, vagrant: nil, favorite_shoe: nil, shipping_address_id: nil, race_manager: false, auto_submission: true, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, referral_credit: #<BigDecimal:7ffdaf4ff920,'0.0',9(18)>, country: nil>, @messages={:email=>["Enter your email address."], :password=>["Enter a password."]}>
```

What's confusing here is that the params clearly show up in the correct place. But then it just rolls back, and the model has nothing on it. I've even turned off all validations, and I still get back errors saying the email and password need to be filled out (when they clearly have been, as shown in the params).

Any ideas are much appreciated! This one's driving me bonkers. Thanks!

UPDATE: From the users suggestions, I checked on gem issues. I rolled back to commits prior to me doing anything, and ran bundle install. The only change was an update to 'Paperclip' from 3.0 -> 3.5.2. This didn't fix anything though. Same problem as before. With the validations back in however, it did produce this log output...

```
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY '' LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Notice that the email is BINARY ''. Normally the actual email address should show up where the '' are. And again, the params are definitely showing up in the logs exactly as typed. Yet, it appears when it goes to do the SQL checks, the fields are all empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Using Rails 3.x?  One guess would be that some gem version got changed and that broke something. What does the `build_resource` method do?

Comment: Yes, using Rails 3.2.8. I'm not actually 100% sure what build_resource does because I didn't write any of that code. I'll look up what it does though. Thanks for the tip about looking into gems. I suppose that could explain why even rolling back to commits before I started coding would still leave it broken. Because I didn't run bundle install after checking out those old commits... let's see.

Comment: I checked on the gem idea. No luck, unfortunately. See the edit in the question. Thanks for any other ideas/feedback you might have!

Comment: See it could depend how your gemfile is written as well - say you just have the line `gem devise`. This will use the newest version of devise. So even if you roll back and rerun `bundle install`, if at some point a newer version of devise came out, you'll be using the new version even on your old commits and not the older devise you were previously using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a wild guess that you're using Devise, since the controller code is nearly identical to `Devise::RegistrationsController`. ([current code here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/ed86361b9289d1af86b9917c005786e81cf92429/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L13))

Nearly - except for the part where `build_resource` is passed the incoming parameters.

You may want to check the Devise version that a working copy of the app (other devs? production?) is using, as some older versions had a `build_resource` method that didn't require an argument.

Comment: This sounds right to me - it would explain why things are coming in as all blank - no parameters are being passed

Comment: My goodness! You're a genius! user3124288's comment about gem devise was exactly right, which explains the problem of rolling back not actually working. Thank you so much! Saved me a lot more frustration!   And to any future googlers, what I actually did to fix it was just do build_resource(params[:user]) instead of simply build_resource. The devise code uses a variable they get from another function, but really you're just passing the params in.